# undefined reference runtime errors __intel_ssse3_rep_memcpy, _mm_free,_mm_malloc linker errors when compiling with gcc instead of icpc

Tags: gcc, linker, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm trying to compile a large code with gcc(5.3), which was compiled with icpc before.(I have mkl libraries loaded) Compilation was successful but with the following warning:

```
 warning: narrowing conversion of 'p_jShell->simint_shell::nprim' from 'int' to
'unsigned int' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
  { p_iShell->nprim, p_jShell->nprim };
```

But I get run time errors 'undefined referece' to __intel_ssse3_rep_memcpy, _mm_free,_mm_malloc,__svml_pow4,_intel_fast_memset etc..

```
In function `simgms_oei(std::vector<std::vector<simint_shell, std::allocator<simint_shell> >, std::allocator<std::vector<simint_shell, std::allocator<simint_shell> > > >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >&, unsigned int, AtomData&)':

/home/..../simgms_oei.cpp:126: undefined reference to `oed__memory_ovl_batch_'
..
..

In function `simint_copy_shell':
shell.c:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to `__intel_ssse3_rep_memcpy'
.
shell.c:(.text+0x32fe): undefined reference to `_mm_free'
shell.c:(.text+0x335c): undefined reference to `_mm_malloc'
.
ostei_p_s_f_p.c:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memset'
.
..
..
```

I suspect this could be from a linking problem. I linked gcc lib directory but I'm not sure what libraries I need to have here. Any suggestions? Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
gcc  -mavx -g -O -O1 -std=c++11 -L/opt/shared/sw/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/5.3.0-rhel6/lib64 -libstdc -libsupc++ -libtsan -libubsan -libvtv -libquadmath -libgcc_s -libgcj  -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/lib/intel64 -libmkl_mc -libmkl_sequential -libmkl_gf_ilp64 -libmkl_avx -libmkl_lapack95_lp64 -libmkl_intel_lp64 -libmkl_core -lmkl_gnu_thread -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/include  -I/opt/shared/sw/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/5.3.0-rhel6/include -I/***/simint/include  -DDEBUG -DMKL_ILP64 -MMD -MP -MF"simgms_init.d" -MT"simgms_init.d" -c -o "simgms_init.o" "../simgms_init.cpp"
```

Comment: My guess is that you're linking with object files and/or libraries that were compiled icpc and so need to be linked against that compiler's runtime libraries.

Comment: I compiled everything with gcc but there were some headers I found were used from intel compiler. Even though they had same name, e.g: immintrin.h from intel was different to immintrin.h in gcc But I have fixed those bugs.

Comment: In gcc's intrinsics headers (mm_malloc.h in this case, but it is included from others as well), _mm_malloc is an inline function. If you are getting such an undefined symbol, either you didn't use gcc, or you used gcc with some other compiler's headers, or you ignored errors about _mm_malloc missing a prototype (aka missing #include).

Comment: Also, the command line you are showing makes no sense, with both `-c` and `-l...` flags. And when linking, you should write A before B when A depends on B, so in particular your .cpp file should come before all `-l...` flags.

Comment: I didn't come across malloc errors, but the code I'm compiling is too big and some modules might have used other compiler headers as you say. Found this helpful: http://hpchcl.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-resolve-undefined-reference-to.html

Comment: warning: narrowing conversion of 'p_iShell->simint_she
ll::nprim' from 'int' to 'unsigned int' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
      { p_iShell->nprim, p_jShell->nprim };
                  ^                                             This was the only warning I ignored.

Comment: I should have just left this as a comment.  Did you try this? https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor

Comment: Thanks. I did try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried found the library all the cpp files(simgms_oei.cpp etc..) were compiled into and tried the nm commands below:

```
>> nm libsimint.a |grep __intel_ssse3_rep_memcpy
U __intel_ssse3_rep_memcpy

>> nm libsimint.a |grep simint_copy_shell
0000000000000090 T simint_copy_shell
```

When you lookup U and T it meant the following:
simint_copy_shell function is mentioned in code but __intel_ssse3_rep_memcpy is not defined in some other libray our libsimint is compiled with

The conclusion is that the library is compiled with icpc and I had to recompile it separately with gcc before linking it in the above step.

Adding Wl, command to the linker script like this:

```
--Wl,--start-group -L/opt/share... -lsomelib -lsomeotherlib -L/xxx/...-lsomelib  -Wl,--end-group
```

Got rid of the other errors I had due to linking order.